# IS there any Django app that notify the user about something that happened in your web, and ask him to perform an action?

Tags: django

I mean, there's any generic app that you can use to make notifications like when in Facebook, someone adds you as friend, or invite you to an event?

Basically, I need to show to the user this type of notification for different contents type, with the possibility to do some custom actions (ignore, accept, etc) different for each one.

I wonder if someone have done this before, so I can plug it and create a type of notification simply passing the text of the notification, the options that must show and the views to call for each option.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128886/django-way-for-building-a-news-feed-status-update-activity-stream

Answer (score 5):

[django-notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) is a GitHub notifications alike app, and it's based on [Django Activity Stream](https://github.com/jazzido/django-activity-stream).

If you familia with django-activity-stream, the the usage of django-notifications almost the same.

django-notifications also provide `notifications_unread` templatetag to display unread notifications of current login user.

Comment: I'm trying to use your app. When UserA creates something, I want to notify UserB, how do I do that?

Comment: use `recipient` Such as 
`notify.send(userA, recipient=userB, verb=u'created', action_object=something, target=destination)`

Answer (score 1):

[Django Activity Stream](https://github.com/jazzido/django-activity-stream) does this, for the most part.  It's a generic relationship manager that watches for save events in the datbase, and when a condition is met it puts an "event happened!" record into its own tables.

It would be incumbent upon you to then present that feed of events to the user, along with links to the actions (specific to your project) that you want him to take.

Even if it's not what you want, it's an excellent example of how to start.

Comment: umm I currently use Django activity stream for, well, just it, do a stream of the things that the user is interested on. I didn't think that could be possible do what I want to do with it. Maybe it's possible, but then I have to sepparate the feed of actions that interest the user from the feed of notifications....

Comment: I'm using django-notifications but the documentation is quite brief.  So I looked into django-activity-stream and found it is more useful, except it doesn't have the `recipient` field which I needed.  I'm thinking either `upgrade` the django-notifications with the follow/following from DAS or the other way around. (sounds like no perfect solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more closer to my needs:
django-notification
https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification

any experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

There is also django-notify: http://code.google.com/p/django-notify/