# Django activity stream : 'str' object has no attribute 'verb'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build something very similar to [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128886/django-way-for-building-a-news-feed-status-update-activity-stream) using django activity stream and honestly facing lots of difficulty to implement it. Also, not getting much reference documentation other than [this](http://justquick.github.com/django-activity-stream/) but finding very difficult to understand.

Suppose User A belongs to Team 1. As soon as User A saved values to model, how should I broadcast this news to all members of Team 1 (except User A) and Team 2 using django activity stream.
Soemthing like 'User A from Team 1 has challenged Team 2. The subject is "*subject*" on date "date_of_test" with total questions "total_questions".

UPDATE:

It seems somewhere I am missing the line. I have created different sample model to test it but its not working.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from actstream import action


class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    action.send(instance, verb='was saved')

post_save.connect(my_handler, sender=Name)
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^activity/', include('actstream.urls')),
    (r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template':'base.html'}),
)
```

Now I want to display the action on template as soon as data gets saved.

## base.html

```
{% load activity_tags %}
<html>
<body>
Hi Sunil
{% display_action action %}
</body>
</html>
```

But its giving error *'str' object has no attribute 'verb'*. I think the problem is with base.html.

Thank you very much for your time,

Sunil

Comment: Can someone please shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake..was thinking django-activity stream has Comet kind of behavior to fetch data. Closing this question after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368137/does-cometlong-polling-needed-for-django-activity-stream).

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward to me. The documentation on [creating actions](http://justquick.github.com/django-activity-stream/actions.html) tells you all you need to know:

```
from actstream import action

action.send(request.user, verb='challenged', target=team_one)
```

*Where `team_one` is an instance of `Team` or similar model, depending on what you named it.*

Comment: Can you please have a look to my question update. I think its something very simple thing i am missing. Many Thanks!!