# Does Comet(long polling) needed for Django activity stream

Tags: python, django

Does anyone has idea how to display django stream actions on templates.

Does I need to use Comet to fetch values to display on my template. Since, When I am doing action.send, it is storing verb and description in table actstream_action. But how should I display the values on template ?

P.S. Please note that this is first time I am using [django-activity stream.](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/)

Comment: Check toolkit like [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio). Or, normally a long-polling is enough.

Comment: @okm:what are the ways to implement long polling in django ? I think django-socketio is also a way to create long polling, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Ah, I mean polling for the second point actually.

Comment: My initial thought was that django-activity stream has some internal mechanism through which we can fetch actions directly to template using various templatetags provided by it. If you think my this assumption is wrong, then please provide your above comment as answer so I can close this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked django-activity-stream, seems it has no magic for rendering activity updating dynamically.

Check [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) for websockets way. Or simply polling tech would satisfy your requirement if the expected access loading is not that high.

I'm not quite sure what you mean about "fetch actions directly to template using various templatetags" because template rendering is accomplished during request-response proceduret.